# Como pintar um gráfico no r a partir de um valor específico?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
x <- seq(0, 15, length.out=10000)

dat <- data.frame(x=x, px=dexp(x, rate = 1/5 ))

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x=x, y=px)) + geom_line()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

eu gostaria de pintar esse gráfico a partir do valor 10, algo como isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para pintar a área debaixo da curva, pode-se usar o `geom_ribbon`.
A base tem de ser reduzida aos valores de `x` a partir do ponto mínimo, neste caso 10.
E deve ser usado antes de `geom_line` para não se sobrepor à linha.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x, y = px)) + 
  geom_ribbon(
    data = subset(dat, x > 10), 
    aes(ymin = 0, ymax = px), 
    fill = "blue") +
  geom_line()
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pode usar `geom_area` no lugar de `geom_ribbon`, assim não precisa especificar outra estética.